# How can I remove the extra space around my Highcharts scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to build an [NBA shot chart](http://a.espncdn.com/photo/2012/1031/grantland_kg_jharden_1152.jpg) generator using Highcharts. So far I've managed to gather the data and plot it, but I'm unable to overlay a court diagram over the chart to finish the job because of the extra space at the right and bottom of the chart.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGaqD.jpg)'s an Imgur gallery demonstrating what I have now and what I'm trying to achieve.

This is the code I'm using to generate the charts:

```
  var drawChart = function(made, missed) {
    $(function () {
      $('#container').highcharts({
          chart: {
              type: 'scatter',
              width: 500,
              height: 470
          },
          title: {
              text: ""
          },
          xAxis: {
            title: {
              enabled: false
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              enabled: false
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0
          },
          legend: {
              layout: 'vertical',
              align: 'left',
              verticalAlign: 'top',
              x: 250,
              y: 400,
              floating: true,
              backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
              borderWidth: 1
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          plotOptions: {
              scatter: {
                  marker: {
                      radius: 5,
                      states: {
                          hover: {
                              enabled: true,
                              lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                          }
                      }
                  },
                  states: {
                      hover: {
                          marker: {
                              enabled: false
                          }
                      }
                  },
                  tooltip: {
                      headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                      pointFormat: '{point.x} ft, {point.y} ft'
                  }
              }
          },
          series: [{
            name: "Made",
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: made
          }, {
            name: "Missed",
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
            data: missed
          }
        ]
      });
    });
  }
```

I've tried fiddling with various spacing and margin options but haven't had any luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a live example, or a jsFiddle? Without seeing HTML and CSS code, I think, we can not help.

Comment: using chart.marginRight and chart.marginBottom should help you with your problem. You may also set min and max of your axes, but it is hard to tell anything without live example of your issue.

Comment: @Grzegorz Blachliński Setting the min and max for my axes was just what I needed. Thanks a lot.